# innerHTML without the html, just text

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've created an e-mail link that automatically populates the necessary information in the body. But, when I do .innerHTML I get a little more than I bargained for.

I want "March, 2012: 12-16"

What I get `<B>March, 2012</B>: <FONT color=blue>12</FONT> - <FONT color=blue>16</FONT>`

Is there a way to get the innerHTML without the html tags?

```
.value = undefined
.text = undefined
```

Comment: I think there's an innerText property...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: ...I searched for like 20 minutes and couldn't find that. : / thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You want `.textContent` in all but older IE, and `.innerText` in IE (<9).

So, try:

`string = (node.textContent===undefined) ? node.innerText : node.textContent;`

**EDIT:** Or, just use GGG's much cleaner `string = (node.innerText || node.textContent)`, since `undefined` is falsy.

Comment: what the... `(node.innerText || node.textContent)`. Although they're not exactly the same...

Comment: Who is GGG? Alter ego?

Comment: @Stanislav http://web.archive.org/web/20120927230726/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727111/innerhtml-without-the-html-just-text#answer-9727182 (See also [If I change my display name, will the change reflect in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59884/if-i-change-my-display-name-will-the-change-reflect-in-comments))

Comment: `innerText` and `textContent` do have slightly different behaviors (i.e. `innerText` takes CSS `display: hidden` into account), so be careful which you use. For my use case, I only wanted human-readable text, for which `innerText` is the solution (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext).

Answer (score 7):

In the browser that supports the standard, you can use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Otherwise you can loop through the next nodes and concatenate them, or using library like jQuery that abstract this approach for you.

Comment: The company is using an older version of IE and textContent returns undefined. innerText worked fine though. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use innerText?

Comment: `innerText` is not exactly `textContent`. If you have to work in a IE-only environment, that's fine I don't see any harm in use it – it's just not standard. Here the refs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using jQuery, you can use .text():

http://jsfiddle.net/vkgYR/

if you are not using it though, you should just go with the other comments since it would be silly to load all of jQuery just for the .text() method