# How to insert text in an HTML document using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I want to replace a `span` element with the `id` "randMsg" with the string `"saying"`. Here is what I have right now:

```
 document.getElementById('randMsg').write(saying);
```

Any ideas? I’m a JavaScript noob, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: .write() is the wrong functions to use. try `document.getElementById('...').innerHTML = ...`

Comment: I am assuming you want to set the text of the span. Try this `document.getElementById('randMsg').innerHTML("saying");`

Comment: Duplicate? [innerHTML without the html, just text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9727111/710446) (I think that question is concerned with *getting* the value, rather than setting it, however.)

Comment: @PSL You're confusing DOM with jQuery. Did you mean `$('#randMsg').innerHTML("saying");` or some such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `textContent` property to update the text inside the element:

```
document.getElementById("randMsg").textContent = "Replaced Content";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RaGng/

Or if you need it to work in IE8 and below, you can detect support for `textContent`, and if it is not supported, you can use the non-standard `innerText` instead:

```
var el = document.getElementById("randMsg"),
    msg = "Replaced Content";

("textContent" in el) ? el.textContent = msg : el.innerText = msg;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RaGng/4/

Comment: Have a look at the support for textContent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: @PSL There are modern browsers, current browsers aaaaannnnd there's IE bringing up the rear as always.

Comment: Fair enough, but then you can use "in" to detect support, and then use innerText if not supported: http://jsfiddle.net/RaGng/3/

Answer (score 1):

The following [W3C DOM code](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) works in all mainstream browsers, including IE8 and older.

```
var node = document.getElementById('randMsg');
var textToUse = 'Hello, World!';

// Remove all the children of the node.
while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}

// Now add the text.
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textToUse));
```

**[Working JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4FTNh/3/)**.

You can also use `innerText`, however, not supported in Firefox:

```
node.innerText = textToUse;
```

Or, you can use `textContent`, however, not supported by IE versions 8 and *older*:

```
node.textContent = textToUse;
```

Quirksmode has very well maintained [browser compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) for all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqyZY/)**

You must set the `innerHTML` property of the element. Consider the following markup:

```
<span id="randMsg"></span>
```

And in your JS code:

```
var saying = 'Say Hello World';
document.getElementById('randMsg').innerHTML = saying;
```

And your result would be:

```
<span id="randMsg">Say Hello World</span>
```

---

#### Note

Don't forget to add this script **after** your element (or wait for DOM ready):

```
<body>
    <span id="randMsg"></span>
    <script>
        var saying = 'Say Hello World';
        document.getElementById('randMsg').innerHTML = saying;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` may not work properly if the text includes characters like `<` or `&`. Sounds like you want `innerText`, which will accept the string as text, but which, of course, lacks Firefox support.