# Text of the HTML checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="One" checked="checked" id="r1" name="g" />

    <label for="r1">
        One
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Two" id="r2" name="g" />

    <label for="r2">
        Two
    </label>

<input type="button" value="Status" onclick="MyFunction()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function MyFunction() {
 var chk = document.getElementsByName("g");
   for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
      if (chk[i].checked == true) {
         alert("Checkbox at index " + i + " is checked!");
         alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].nextSibling.innerHTML);
         }
     }
}
```

Here I am getting the Index of the checkboxes which are checked. 
How to get the text of the selected Checkboxes?

**Demo**:http://jsfiddle.net/u95uN/

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 2):

Because in many browsers, the `nextSibling` will be an empty text node.

USE [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) instead of `nextSibling`

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/g5CGc/)

> The ChildNode.nextElementSibling read-only property returns the
>   element immediately following the specified one in its parent's
>   children list, or null if the specified element is the last one in the
>   list.

```
function MyFunction() {
         var chk = document.getElementsByName("g");
         for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {

             if (chk[i].checked === true) {
                 alert("Checkbox at index " + i + " is checked!");
                 alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML);

             }
         }

     }

     MyFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! btw what is difference between nextElementSibling.innerHTML and nextElementSibling.innerText?

Comment: @Johnny http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727111/innerhtml-without-the-html-just-text .Make my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with jQuery I'll answer using jQuery.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xL56/3/

Explanation:
On button click:

```
$("#btn").click
```

It will run through every checkbox with the name "g":

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=g]").each
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `chk[i].value` to fetch the value of the checked checkbox.

```
alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].value);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u95uN/6/)

Comment: Yes, but i want the Text, not the value.

Comment: This solution will work as long as the value equals the text. Otherwise, use Samitha's solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You are writing `JavaScript` on load, mention in head or body as below:

```
 function MyFunction() {
     var chk = document.getElementsByName("g");
       for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {

          if (chk[i].checked === true) {
            alert("Checkbox at index " + i + " is checked!");
           alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].nextElementSibling.innerText);

             }
         }
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u95uN/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this line !

```
alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerText);
```

Or you can use;

```
alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].nextElementSibling.innerText);
```

Or you can use; (My way)

```
alert("Text at index " + i + chk[i].value);
```

To see this options, you can write in javascript your code "**console.log(chk[i])**" than you can see your options to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think this would work :

```
$.each($("input[name='g']:checked"),function(i,element){
    var id = $(element).attr("id");
    var text = $("label[for='"+id+"']").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling`

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u95uN/8/)**

`nextSibling` checks for whatever there is following the current element and hence even `line-break` or `space` etc are also considered even if these are not HTML elements and `nextSibling()` is only for that.

But `nextElementSibling` searches for the next HTML element that here is the `<label>` and hence it is what you need.