# JavaScript select only inner html of outer element excluding inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch inner html of an Element which has inner element like this

```
  <span> Hello How <span>a</span> re You</span>
```

I want fetch only **Hello how re You** but I am getting like this :

```
   Hello How <span>a</span> re You
```

This is my javascript code:

```
  <script>
 
      $(document).ready(function(){
          
         var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
          for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
              
              
              alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
          }
          
          
      });
     
    
  </script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: Also you can find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727111/innerhtml-without-the-html-just-text

Answer (score 1):

You can either clone the `element` then remove the child elements and get the contents or filter out the inner content

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   var $spans = $("span");
   //first way
   $spans.each(function() {
     var text = $(this).clone().find('*').remove().end().text();
     snippet.log('1: ' + text)
   });

   //second way
   $spans.each(function() {
     var text = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
     }).text();
     snippet.log('2: ' + text)
   })



 });
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> Hello How <span>a</span> re You</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery way.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
           var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
          for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
             alert($(spans[i]).text()); // Changed here
          }
 });
```

[Jsfiddle using jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/ro03p70b/)

Using javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
          for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
             alert(spans[i].textContent); // Using textContent
          }
 });
```

[jsfiddle with javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/ro03p70b/1/)

**EDIT** after comments
If you are looking for only " Hello How a re You" you need to only retrieve the text form first `NodeList` of span.

In jquery way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sp = $('span');
         alert($(sp[0]).text())
 });
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro03p70b/2/)

Comment: No i dont want "a" that is of a inner element text. I just want "hello how re You"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
alert($("span")[0].innerHTML.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*>/gm, ''));
```

```html
<span> Hello How <span>a</span> re You</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```